# How Many Fields is Bruce Wayne Accomplished In?

Tags: dc, comics, batman

While I'm more familiar with the movies and TV shows than the comics, in various versions of Batman, I've seen him show expertise in chemistry, nuclear physics (in the 1960s Batman, he had a nuclear reactor in the Batcave), martial arts, computer science, and more.

While I know each movie and TV show essentially will create it's own canon, in the comic books, how many different fields has Bruce Wayne reached some level of accomplishment in?  (By accomplished, I mean that he's reached a working knowledge or skill level in that field so that he can actually use that knowledge or skill as weapon or tool in his arsenal.)

Comment: I'm a little cautious about "Baman has" vs. "Batman is an expert in". E.g. is it confirmed that he operates the nuclear reactor in Batcave, as opposed to Alfred or someone from Wayne industries?

Comment: I don't think this question can be answered. It's not enough to set aside television and movies, you'd have to pick a writer, a universe, a time and place...You would even need to pick a Batman.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is generally agreed upon among all versions of Batman that he is "The World's Greatest Detective."  That being said, he has shown skill in certain areas across all versions:

- Forensic Science
- Criminal Psychology
- Fingerprint Analysis
- Criminal Profiling
- Chemistry
- Human Anatomy
- Information Technology
- Communication Technology
- Forensic Pathology

He is also shown to be fluent in an indeterminate number of languages including French, Spanish, Russian, Japanese, and Chinese.

As far as his martial arts training, sometimes he is said to be a "Master" of all known martial arts, and other times just to have studied the "Major" ones and combined several into his own style. He has demonstrated knowledge of:

- Shao-Lin Wushu
- Judo
- Aikido
- Capoera
- Savate
- Jujitsu
- Ninjutsu
- Karate
- Krav Maga
- Muay Tai
- Eskrima
- Sambo
- Traditional Boxing

He is also shown to be highly skilled in the areas of:

- Manhunting
- Escapology
- Misdirection
- Sleight of Hand
- Psychological Intimidation
- First Aid (Combat Medic)
- Interrogation

In some versions he is shown to also have skill as a mechanic and engineer, at other times these duties are handled by either Alfred or Harold Alnut.

While not necessarily fields of knowledge in the traditional sense, he has also shown great skill in Lateral Thinking and Deductive Reasoning.

Comment: Where did he demonstrate knowledge of Capoeira ? I'd love to know :)

Comment: @Kalissar he wouldn't use the ginga, which is the commonly known basic step of capoeira (the basic back and forth step) but he has used a kick sometimes referred to as a rodeo kick, a rodeo, or a scissor kick which is commonly used in capoeira.

Comment: Also he's very accomplished at prefixing stuff with the word _Bat_.

Comment: Just a statement: Forensic science would include Forensic Pathology and Fingerprint Analysis. Criminal Psychology would include Criminal Profiling. His Information Technology skill could include Computer Infiltration, Communication and Security technology.

As far as his martial arts, the Kung Fu disciplines he would probably be using would not be Shao-Lin Wushu, it would more likely be Wing Chun because of its close contact, fast hand action and reaction. Wushu tends to be more ornamental and display-oriented.

Comment: Also he is skilled with riding horses, driving cars, motocycles, planes. In Dark Knight Rises he actually programmed the autopilot for his batcopter (but that is a movie, not a comic). Presumably he also is a skilled marksman, although he uses guns very sporadically.